# How to disable auth for SPARQL in Anzograph?

Tags: sparql, anzograph

Is it possible to disable authentication for the SPARQL 1.1 endpoint? Authentication is a good idea for SPARQL 1.1 Update but we have use cases where we would like SPARQL 1.1 to be open.

I've also looked at the [Systems Settings Reference](https://docs.cambridgesemantics.com/anzograph/v2.2/userdoc/settings-ref.htm) but couldn't find anything relevant.